# How do i style a list within a list?

Tags: html, css

I have a list within a list, but I don't want the inner list to receive the outer list's styles. This is my code:

CSS:

```
li {
    background-color:red;
}

#sections li {
    color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol id="sections">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>
<ol><li>Item A</li>
<li>Item C</li>
</ol>
</ol>
```

I could just set `color` to whatever my default is, but that's sort of a hack, and in the future if i add something to the `#sections li` style it could mess with the inner list style, so I presume this is bad coding form.

How do i make the inner list be unaffected by the outer list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May want to instead do a new style for nested lists, like this:

```css
ol ol li,
ol ul li,
ul ol li,
ul ul li
{
    /* Nested list styles */
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
```

You could also use the [`>` child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) to just target top level `<li>`s:

```css
ol#selections > li
{
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is

```
ul li {color:blue}
ul li li {color:white;}
```

just change the second color